# Getting the value of a (perhaps un-applied) CSS attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following CSS

```
.EggChart {
    width: 5000px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

and would like to read the value of `height` from the CSS class specification, either using raw JavaScript or in jQuery. If the class has been applied to an element of the DOM this seems straightforward: I'd select the elements of the DOM with this class and read their CSS attributes, but if the class **has not been applied to any DOM element** how would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple CSS properties with fixed, constant values such as the ones given above, you can create a dummy element, then get the computed value for the property you're looking for.

Using vanilla JavaScript:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'EggChart';
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('height'));
```

Using jQuery:

```
console.log($('<div class="EggChart"></div>').css('height'));
```

Comment: That certainly works (+1) but is it really the only way; are we unable to access the CSS specifications in a page through JavaScript directly?

Comment: @dumbledad: You'll have to parse the document stylesheet, which is an entirely different league in itself...

Comment: Eek - too right! That I do not want to embark on.

Comment: @dumbledad For direct manipulation of CSS stylesheet through JS, take a look here: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript